# SVN on a shared server

Tags: svn, authentication, shared-hosting

I am trying to set up svn on a shared host.  The host has already installed it and I have created a repo that I can connect to using svn+ssh, but because it's shared hosting, I can't add users, so I am trying to use the svnserve.conf and passwd files to add users that way but when I try to do:

```
svn list svn://svn.myDomain.org
```

I get a message that says:

```
Authentication realm: <svn://svn.myDomain.org:3690>
Password for 'cborders':
```

But when I put in the password that I have set up in the passwd file it gives me the same Authentication realm message and asks for a username, then a password.  It does this two more times and then fails out completely.

These are the only lines that are not commented out in my svnserev.conf file:

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd

[sasl]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does `pgrep -fl svnserve` output?

Comment: 21658 svnserve -d -r /home2/machwe5/public_html/svn/Projects/

Answer (score 0):

probably best to add your svnserver.conf file to your question. I think you've got the realm in the [general] section wrong.

Comment: Actually the realm is commented out.  I am putting my svnserve.conf file above.

Comment: the default realm is the repo uuid, so its picking it up from somewhere. Try putting one in!

Comment: I put in a realm that I am sure is unique to the shared host and I still get the same issue.